# C# ORA-12154 TNS: невозможно разрешить имя службы

Tags: c#, oracle

Отказал ж.диск на моем ПК(где до меня была установлена Visual Studio 2017 Professional (Версия 15.5.6) + 
клиент Oracle 11.2
BOOTSTRAP_COMPS="oracle.swd.oui:11.2.0.2.0,oracle.swd.oui.core:11.2.0.2.0,oracle.jdk:1.5.0.24.08")

После установки Visual Studio 2017 Professional (версия 15.6.7) на другой ПК(с Oracle client 9.2) из VS\VS17_NET
не подключаются к Oracle с ошибкой:

> ORA-12154: TNS:невозможно разрешить имя службы

из компонентов:

```
namespace Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data {public static class DatabaseFactory
```

и

```
namespace System.Data.OracleClient {
// Сводка: Предоставляет открытое подключение к базе данных. Этот класс не наследуется.
[DefaultEvent("InfoMessage")][Obsolete("OracleConnection has been deprecated. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=144260", false)]
public sealed class OracleConnection
```

Но при этом из PL/SQL Navigator подключается 
и через класс OracleDataAdapter  тоже:

```
namespace System.Data.OracleClient { [DefaultEvent("RowUpdated")]
[Designer("Microsoft.VSDesigner.Data.VS.OracleDataAdapterDesigner, Microsoft.VSDesigner, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")]
[ToolboxItem("Microsoft.VSDesigner.Data.VS.OracleDataAdapterToolboxItem, Microsoft.VSDesigner, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")]
public sealed class OracleDataAdapter
```

Что является причиной и как добиться работы с базой из всех классов?

Comment: то есть у вас был клиент 11 версии - все работало, стал 9й - перестало работать, верно?

Comment: вы серьезно думаете что Oracle client 9.2  будет работать Oracle server 11.2, он даже с 10 не будет работать)

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/index.html
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html

Comment: Я повторяю, что PL/SQL Navigator подключается через клиент  client 9.2 к серверу server 11.2 и прекрасно работает. 
Проблема в том, что Visual Studio не находит TNS файл!
Установка дополнительно клиента 12.2 ничего не изменила!
Sqlplus подключается, а Visual Studio - нет !